# Can a computationally-unbounded adversary break any cipher which is not perfectly secret?

Tags: perfect-secrecy

Imagine we have a cipher defined as $(K, M, C, E, D)$ which is not perfectly secret, namely:

$\exists m_0, m_1 \in M, c \in C \text{ s.t. } P[k \leftarrow K; E(k, m_0) = c] \neq P[k \leftarrow K; E(k, m_1) = c]$

Is it the case that this fact alone is enough to deduce that there exists an unbounded adversary who can break this cipher under semantic security? I believe the answer is yes, but I want to confirm.

Comment: What does the semicolon mean in your probability expression? Should it be a comma, or a conditional bar?

Comment: What do you mean by the break? Remember, the adversary's real aim is decrypting the messages or forging signatures. Getting the key is not the real aim. For example, we can decrypt messages if the nonce is repeated in AES-CTR with a two-time pad, however, we may not get the AES-CTR's key.